# Linear combinations of jointly normal random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Here is the definition of joint normality in my textbook.

**Def:** Two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are said to be jointly normal if they have the joint density $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)\\=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_1\sigma_2\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\left[ \frac{(x-\mu_1)^2}{\sigma_1^2} - \frac{2\rho(x-\mu_1)(y-\mu_2)}{\sigma_1 \sigma_2} +\frac{(y-\mu_2)^2}{\sigma_2^2} \right] \right\},$$

where $\sigma_1 >0, \sigma_2>0,|\rho|<1,$ and $\mu_1,\mu_2$ are real numbers.

My textbook states without proof that this definition is equivalent to the statement that linear combinations of jointly normal random variables are still jointly normal.

I tried to google a proof for this equivalence but I didn't manage to find one. Can anyone help me with proving the $(\Longrightarrow)$ direction? Thanks.

---

Textbook page:

[image: Related textbook page]

*Stochastic calculus for finance II Continuous time models*, Steven E. Shreve.

Comment: It is easier to use characteristic functions instead of density functions.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Can you explain a bit more? Thanks. But unfortunately I cannot choose the definition.

Comment: the pdf above can be rewritten as $f_{X,Y}(v)=\frac1{2\pi \sqrt{\det \Sigma }}e^{-\frac1{2}(v-\mu )^\top \Sigma ^{-1}(v-\mu )}$ where $\mu:=(\mathrm{E}X,\mathrm{E}Y)$ is the mean of $(X,Y)$ and $\Sigma $ its [covariance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix)

Comment: @Masacroso Thanks for the comment. Yes, I know this vector form of the pdf. But I still don't know how to prove, say $X+Y$ and $Y$ have a joint pdf as $f_{X+Y,Y}(v)=\frac1{2\pi \sqrt{\det \Sigma }}e^{-\frac1{2}(v-\mu )^\top \Sigma ^{-1}(v-\mu )}$, where $\mu=(EX+EY,EY)$ and $\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix of $X+Y$ and $Y$. Can you give me some hints? Thanks.

Comment: @SamWong I guess you understood wrongly the statement: $(X+Y,X)$ is not a linear combination of jointly normals. What the statement in reality says that $(X,Y)$ is jointly normal if and only if $aX+bY$ is normal for any chosen $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Equivalent_definitions)

Comment: @Masacroso I see. I have looked at the Wikipedia page and the statement you mentioned is more reasonable to me. But it seems like that the author of the textbook understood the equivalence in this wrong way. Can you help me check the underlined sentences on the textbook page which I just uploaded? Thanks. I don't really understand why $X$ and $W$ are jointly normal on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sketch for a proof, too long for a comment:** I understand that the statement of the book marked in red says that if $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal then $aX+bY$ and $cX+dY$ are jointly normal also, for arbitrary $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{R}$. This means that the random variable $(a,c)X+(b,d)Y$ must be multivariate normal, if we follow the definition of jointly normal of wikipedia.

Setting $J:=(a,c)X+(b,d)Y$ this amount to compute it density, given by

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Pr [J\in (-\infty ,s]\times (-\infty ,t]]=\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_{\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:ax+by\leqslant s, cx+dy\leqslant t\}}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,d (x,y)\tag1
$$

and show that it is of the desired form. As said in the comments an equivalent condition is easily proved using characteristic functions.

For a direct proof using (1) probably you will need to use some linear algebra, specially knowledge about positive definite matrices, and the theorem of change of variables for the integral.

Comment: Thanks for the post. What is $(a,c)$? Is it the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $c$?

Comment: @SamWong its a vector $(a,c)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $(a,c)X$ is scalar multiplication, as $X$ is real valued. That is $(a,c)X+(b,d)Y=(aX+bY,cX+dY)$